# while executing queryIntentActivities android it does not return com.android.bluetooth

Tags: android

While executing the below code I am not getting the `com.android.bluetooth` in android 4.2.1 but when i execute the same peice of code in 4.1.2 `com.android.bluetooth` appears in the list. Is it a version problem or device problem?

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
            List<ResolveInfo> appsList = pm.queryIntentActivities( in, 0);

            if(appsList.size() > 0){
                //select bluetooth
                String packageName = null;
                String className = null;
                boolean found = false;

                for(ResolveInfo info: appsList){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, packageName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  packageName = info.activityInfo.packageName;
                  if( packageName.equals("com.android.bluetooth")){
                     className = info.activityInfo.name;
                     found = true;
                     break;// found
                  }
                }
                if(! found){
                  Toast.makeText(this, "not found",
                                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  // exit
                }
                else{
                    in.setClassName(packageName, className);
                    startActivity(in);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score -2):

You may want to try **com.mediatek.bluetooth** as package name in your code instead of **com.android.bluetooth**. Apparently, new Android versions use this package. This worked for me.